# Go channels seem not to be blocking although supposed to be

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am new to golang and have a hard time understanding how the channels work. My understanding is that by default, channels are supposed to be blocking, so I expect a goroutine that writes into a channel to be frozen by the scheduler until an other goroutine reads the channel content. So I tried the following code, which gives the corresponding output:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var v int

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    wg.Add(2)
    go func(ch chan string) {
        fmt.Println("Ready to receive")
        for msg := range ch {
            fmt.Println("received: ", msg)
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(ch)
    go func(ch chan string) {
        fmt.Println("Will send the SMS to mama")
        ch <- "msg 1"
        v += 1
        fmt.Println("Done! sent the message 1")
        ch <- "msg 2"
        v += 1
        fmt.Println("Done! sent the message 2")
        ch <- "msg 3"
        v += 1
        fmt.Println("Done! sent the message 3")
        close(ch)
        wg.Done()
    }(ch)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

output:

```
Will send the SMS to mama
Ready to receive
received:  msg 1
0
Done! sent the message 1
Done! sent the message 2
received:  msg 2
2
received:  msg 3
2
Done! sent the message 3
```

I am a bit surprised as I was expecting the following order:

1. msg 1 sent
2. msg 1 received
3. msg 2 sent
4. msg 2 received

and so on. But this is obviously not the case.

Does someone have any idea on why Go behaves this way? Many thanks,

Here is a link to the code https://play.golang.org/p/O6SXf0CslPf. And here are my sources for stating what I said earlier:  https://medium.com/rungo/anatomy-of-channels-in-go-concurrency-in-go-1ec336086adb https://rakyll.org/scheduler/

Comment: Sending on / receiving from a channel only guarantees the send and receive to be synchronized. There is no guarantee on the timing of subsequent print operations.

Comment: There is a data race on `v`.   You can expect the print statements before the send operation to occur before the print statements after the receive operation and that is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @CeriseLimón Does this mean that we only have a guarantee that the sending takes place before the receive operation? Don't we have any guarantee that the scheduler will switch to the receiver goroutine at the exact moment it reads this statement for example `ch <- "msg 1"`?

Comment: @A.Luc Any of the goroutine can continue (Possibly in Parallel more than 1 at same at same time) after unbuffered channel synchronization unless further synchronized.

Comment: @A.Luc Here are the relevant quote from the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7):  *A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes.*   There are no other guarantees regarding scheduling of the goroutines on the the channel operation.

Comment: Understood, thanks everyone. Indeed, adding further synchronization makes things happen in the desired order. Many thanks once more ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is completely normal so to answer your question

> so I expect a goroutine that writes into a channel to be frozen by the scheduler until an other goroutine reads the channel content

Schedular may or may not continue that same goroutine after value is sent through channel unless further synchronization is needed.

So for example After "msg 2" is sent to `ch` and is read in another goroutine in the following line

`ch <- "msg 2"`

goroutine can continue to execute `v += 1` and call `fmt.Println` before other goroutine calls it.

Also calls to `fmt.Println` from different goroutines requires synchronization and possibly `mutex` calls which may also reorder print statements.

Further more there is data race on variable `v`